# Running threaded module with celery; daemonic processes are not allowed to have children

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, queue, celery

I have implemented a queue with celery in my flask app. Everything works good.
But I need to use [this module called sublist3r](https://github.com/aboul3la/Sublist3r) and when I use it in a celery task I recieve this error:

```
[2019-02-16 21:32:52,658: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-6] Task tasks.task.addd[57793628-de25-4c89-a265-5fee69a8b2bf] succeeded in 0.0236732449848s: None
[2019-02-16 21:32:52,660: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/me/code/proj/tasks/task.py", line 15, in getd
    sub = sublist3r.main(url, 40, None, ports=None, silent=True,verbose=False, enable_bruteforce=False, engines=None)
  File "/home/me/code/proj/sublist3r/sublist3r.py", line 871, in main
    subdomains_queue = multiprocessing.Manager().list()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 99, in Manager
    m.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 524, in start
    self._process.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 124, in start
    'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
**AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children**
```

Does this happen because I'm trying to use a module that uses threads?
How could I achieve using this module either in a queue or asynchronously?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It appears that `sublist3r` uses multiprocessing and tries to kick off its own processes.  You can't really do that within celery, because in production, celery will already kick off a worker in its own child process, and as you can tell from the error message, celery will not allow you to kick of the multiprocessing processes that sublist3r uses. If you want to use it, your best bet is to rewrite those classes in sublist3r yourself to derive from `celery.Task` instead of `multiprocessing.Process`.